# How to mocha test as an auth0 user on expressjs app?

Tags: express, mocha.js, passport.js, auth0

Sorry for a newbie question, I am still new to mocha. I have an existing app that I am tasked to create a mocha test case. This app uses `passport-auth0` and `passport` for user login. How do write mocha test such that I can login as a dummy user to test restricted functions?

Comment: Please show us how Mocha is causing you a problem. If you are able to log in as a dummy user when you are not using Mocha, then you should be able to do it with Mocha too.

Answer (score 3):

Since Passport uses strategies that can be swapped in, one option is to put a mock in place of the actual `auth0` strategy when running tests.  That would look something like:

```
function MockStrategy() {
}

MockStrategy.prototype.authenticate = function(req) {
    self.success({ id: 1, username: 'joe' );
}

// In test setup, mock out the strategy with one that returns
// dummy data.
passport.use('auth0', new MockStrategy());
```

Now you can write test cases where `req.user` will always be the `joe` as supplied by the mock strategy.  You can extend that to cover authentication failures in a similar way.

That is my preferred approach, as it is least intrusive.  Depending on how the application code is structured, there may be other dependencies that get required and need to be mocked out.  For those situations, I've found [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) to be useful.